# How to store files in local storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am building an online code editor. Currently, I am storing the source file and input file on my server. Is there any way to store the source files on the client-side? I am using UUID to generate a random filename but want to keep it main.c, main.CPP, just online GDB. But if I cannot have a constant file name or collide when other users are using it.

the code to generate the file

```
const path = require("path");
const { v4: uuid } = require("uuid");

const dirCodes = path.join(__dirname, "codes");
const inputPath = path.join(__dirname, "inputs");

if (!fs.existsSync(dirCodes)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(dirCodes, { recursive: true });
}
if (!fs.existsSync(inputPath)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(inputPath, { recursive: true });
}

const generateFile = async (jobId, format, content, input) => {
  const filename = `${jobId}.${format}`;
  const inputFileName = `${jobId}.txt`;
  const inputFilePath = path.join(inputPath, inputFileName);
  const filepath = path.join(dirCodes, filename);
  await fs.writeFileSync(filepath, content);
  await fs.writeFileSync(inputFilePath, input);
  return [filepath, inputFileName];
};

module.exports = {
  generateFile,
};
```

code for executing the file

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { v4: uuid } = require("uuid");

const dirCodes = path.join(__dirname, "codes");
const inputPath = path.join(__dirname, "inputs");

if (!fs.existsSync(dirCodes)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(dirCodes, { recursive: true });
}
if (!fs.existsSync(inputPath)) { random file names will not work for java as we run the class name
  fs.mkdirSync(inputPath, { recursive: true });
}

const generateFile = async (jobId, format, content, input) => {
  const filename = `${jobId}.${format}`;
  const inputFileName = `${jobId}.txt`;
  const inputFilePath = path.join(inputPath, inputFileName);
  const filepath = path.join(dirCodes, filename);
  await fs.writeFileSync(filepath, content);
  await fs.writeFileSync(inputFilePath, input);
  return [filepath, inputFileName];
};

module.exports = {
  generateFile,
};
```

I want to keep the file name constant. Also, random file names will not work for java as we run the classname.class file.
Please let me know if can store the file in client side or local storage

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately browsers don't allow Filesystem access for clients as it is a security risk.

If you want to avoid saving files in the server, then you can use localStorage/sessionStorage to persist data accross sessions at the client level.
Then in your case, you'll have a button to "download" the code directory.

Comment: Some browsers allow filesystem access using the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

Answer (score 0):

- we have 2 ways to save some data.

  ```
  1. localStorage [ permanently ] 
  2. sessionStorage [ hinges on session ]
  ```

for `both`, the function goes with `a string format` of your file.

- to **save** some data - `localStorage.set('data', JSON.stringify(data))`
- to **retrieve** those data - `JSON.parse(localStorage.get('data'))`

the reason we use for parsing is to **convert back** to its own format `[ object/array ]`

- to remove data from storage - localStorage.remove('data')

Comment: sessionStorage is not permanently, its only there for that session, if you close the tab and reopen its gone

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.localStorage.setItem(jobId, content);
```

If the content is a JSON object you can use

```
window.localStorage.setItem(jobId, JSON.stringify(content));
```

And retrieve it like this:

```
let json_object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(jobId));
```

Comment: files cannot be store to browser storage